# Creating nested models in rails, through an other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've a stock, and a calving model.
A stock (has an id, name, and a mother_id) can have carves through a calving, so I have this in my stock model.

```
    has_many :stocks, through: :calvings
    has_many :calvings
```

In Calving model i have:

```
    has_many :calves, class_name: "Stock", foreign_key: "mother_id", 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :calves
```

I have a form for creating Calving, where the user can:

-choose the stock_id (it will be the mother)
-add how many carves was born
-give a name for every carf (depending on the nr of carves born)

I would like to save this data, but when it creates the Stock record, it puts the carving.id into the stock.mother_id field, not the carving.stock_id.

How can i fix this?

And if it is possible, what should I do, to fill the form with the right data when I want to edit the record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [**has_many :through**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

If you're creating records in a `has_many :through` association, you first need to create the records for the join model, then pass the records through the "child" model

Here's how we do it:

---

**Models**

```
#app/models/stock.rb
Class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :calvings, class_name: "Calving"
    has_many :calves, class_name: "Calf", through: :calvings

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :calving

    #build relevant objects (DRYes up controller)
    def self.build 
        stock = self.new
        stock.calvings.build.build_calf
        stock
    end
end

#app/models/calving.rb
Class Calving < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :stock
   belongs_to :calf 

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :calf
end

#app/models/calf.rb
Class Calf < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :calvings, class_name: "Calving"
   has_many :stocks, class_name: "Stock", through: :calvings
end

stocks #needs to identify mother only
id | name | created_at | updated_at

calvings
id | stock_id | calf_id | extra | info | created_at | updated_at

calfs
id | name | extra | information | created_at | updated_at
```

---

**Controllers**

These models give you a structure where you'll have a join model (which holds the relation between `stocks` and `calves`, allowing you to populate them as required:

```
#app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb
def new
    @stock = Stock.build
end

def create
    @stock = Stock.new(stock_params)
    @stock.save
end

private

def stock_params
    parmas.require(:stock).permit(:name, calvings_attributes: [calf_attributes:[:info]]
end
```

---

**Forms**

Finally, you'll be able create the form as follows:

```
#app/views/stocks/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @stock do |f| %> 
    <%= f.name %>
    <%= f.fields_for :calvings do |c| %>
        <%= c.fields_for :calf do |calf| %>
            <%= calf.text_field :info %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Update**

[Rails, self-referential association on the User model to define friends/followers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497582/rails-self-referential-association-on-the-user-model-to-define-friends-follower)

Might be able to do it like this:

```
#app/models/stocks.rb
Class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :calvings
   has_many :calves, class_name: "Stock", through: :calvings
end

#app/models/calvings.rb
Class Calving < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :mother, :class_name => "Stock", foreign_key: "mother_id"
end
```

I'm not actually sure about this to be honest -- needs more thought. Typically, you'd use a standard `has_many :through` relationship for it. I'll email to get a call going - we need to fix this!!!

Comment: I know :) I think your problem is you're trying to self-reference the table, but pass nested attributes to another. In your stock db, I suppose you literally just want to list all the cows with the "calves" being assigned to a particular mother (through `mother_id`)?

Comment: If this is the case, I would recommend ditching the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and populating the `calving` table manually (I think). I can re-write the answer if you wish

Comment: thx for the answer, my only problem, that in my case there is no Calf table. Stock = Calf, so the new born as to be stored in the stock table too, and my main problem is creating the calving, with the form. I have a different page for creating stocks, there are no nested attributes, the new (kid)stock create only happens, when a calving is created.

Comment: oops, sry i deleted the first comment, but my problem is in the other one too. and yeah, its some kind of a self reference. im really new to ruby, if you can help me with that, i'd be very happy :)

Comment: one more, so i just want to store the calving, create the new stocks (later on the can have calvings too), and if a user edits a calving, i want to show the stocks for that particular calving (calving.date==stock.birthday).

Comment: Hey sorry about not replying yet. Got caught doing something yesterday -- working on it now :)

Comment: the problem, that this line in calving.rb:  'belongs_to :mother, :class_name => "Stock", foreign_key: "mother_id"'   puts the calving.id into the new Stock's stock.mother_id. the correct way would be, that when it creates a new Stock, and puts calving.stock_id into stock.mother_id

Comment: Email sent - we need to talk on chat about this